# How do you link Firebase Authentication login with device authentication methods such as facial recognition?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am implementing login-related features using `firebase_auth`, but how can I implement login when using facial recognition in Flutter? One idea I came up with is to save the email and password in local storage and retrieve the values from there after a successful facial recognition, but if I use Firebase's `sendPasswordResetEmail` to change the password, the locally stored password won't be updated as it doesn't receive notification of the change.

How do you all handle the integration of Firebase login with device authentication methods like facial recognition?